# Is it possible to move non system but data software RAID-1 to different system

Tags: linux, debian, backup, raid, software-raid

I promise I did some research before I ask this question. Still not sure about that. Here is what I am planning to do.

I am building a backup server. I am using 2 small HDD software raid-1 for the system Debian in my case. Another 2 big software HDD raid-1 for data/backup. System raid-1 is not that important since all data/backup on data raid-1. But I am not sure if system raid-1 failed, how can I use my data raid-1 on another system to access my data/backup. Is it possible?

And BTW, is it a good solution to create a backup server like that? I only have 2 small HDD and 2 big HDD for now. So ZFS or other raid is no possibility for me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Moving an mdadm software raid is possible, you will need the config and fstab, though (or at least it is simpler that way). Check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/944564/moving-raid-5-to-another-computer), it applies to simpler RAID systems, too.

Comment: Cool, thanks. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

ZFS will work with two HDDs as you can create a mirror with the two data drives. You can also use different setups like LVM.

When the system fails and you need to boot from a bootable image for instance you can use `zpool import` in case of ZFS to seek for ZFS pools which can be imported or use `pvscan` on LVM to seek for those setups.

These kind of tools will scan labels on the drives to see if they can handle them. This is independent from the OS instance running.

And I also prefer to have the OS separated from the data disks.

Comment: OK, I see. Thanks a lot for the comment. I will try ZFS then. So in one word, with ZFS, the pool is indenpentent from the OS. I can easily recover data in any other OS. Good to learn.

Comment: Did some research and found out with ZFS better using ECC also 1gb/1Tb proportion is recommended. My 2 big HDD is 14TB each. 32 GB ECC Ram .... No way man no way.

Comment: Disks are slow compared to memory. Therefor in most cases you will benefit with lots of memory to utilize filesystem cache. ZFS is not an exception, this applies to most filesystems. For heavily used file servers I can recommend putting in some memory so the filesystem cache can be used more effectively, but in your case setting up a backup server I won't worry to much about this.